# Unmet Dependencies when I try to install wine or skype

Tags: installation, wine, skype, multiarch

I have a dell inspiron 64 bit and I'm running both windows 7 and Ubuntu in dual boot

I am having trouble installing skype and wine.

When I try to install skype etc I get the following error:

```
 sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
>   may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   Blockquote
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Is your current Ubuntu a clean install, or have you updated from an old version?

Comment: Sounds like your multiarch is broken. What's the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ia32-libs on 12.04 LTS (32 Bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143904/how-to-install-ia32-libs-on-12-04-lts-32-bit) and [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237)

Answer (score 1):

Type following commands to fix this problem

First remove Wine completely

> sudo apt-get purge wine skype

Fix dependencies

> sudo apt-get install -f

Remove unnecessary packages

> sudo apt-get autoremove

Clean Cache

> sudo apt-get clean

Update system

> sudo apt-get update

Install wine and skype

> sudo apt-get install wine skype