# Unmet Dependencies when installing Wine, ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, apt, wine, dependencies

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, 64 bit, and I can't install wine.  I've tried the solutions presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217455/unmet-dependencies-when-i-try-to-install-wine-or-skype) and [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), but to no avail.

When I use the command `sudo apt-get install wine`, the terminal returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.`
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I install wine if these solutions do not work?

EDIT:  It should be noted that I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 13.04 and Win7
EDIT:  By following theseI was able to successfully install wine.  Whether or not this is a result of all of the answers *and* these results, or just these results, I'm not sure.